# Ruby on Rails 3 Get Dropbox folder contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, directory, dropbox

I am trying to develop an app which will retrieve a list of files and folders inside a specific Dropbox folder (from a user-specified folder). What would be the best way around doing this? Possibly some code snipplets if possible as I am still new to Rails.

Comment: I've had a look but it doesn't have an obvious way to do this. I want to be able to look inside a shared folder (no matter who authenticates, it will always be the same folder - not relative to the user's account)

Comment: The way the Dropbox API works is that a folder is *always* relative to a user's account. So you'll need to authenticate your calls with an access token for a user who has access to the folder you're interested in.